# A sequence of continuous functions that converges pointwise, but not in the uniform metric

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $C[-1, 1]$ be the space of continuous functions equipped with the metric $(f, g) = \displaystyle\max_{x \in [-1, 1]} |f(x)-g(x)|$.

Consider the sequence $(f_n)$ of functions $f_n : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, denoted by
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
     0 & x \in [-1, 0],\\
     nx & x \in [0, \frac{1}{n}],\\
     1 & x \in [\frac{1}{n}, 1]
\end{cases}.$$

Show that the sequence $(f_n)$ does not converge in $C[-1, 1]$.

For this problem, I have shown that if $f_n$ converges to $f$, then $f$ has to be $0$ for $x \in [-1, 0]$ and $f$ has to be $1$ for large $x$. Then what should I do?

Comment: Is the final $f$ you get continuous?

Comment: I only get f at the beginning and at the end, but what about the middle part?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a few of the functions?

Comment: yes, but how to show that f is discontinuous?

Comment: Take a look at what happens around $x=0$. Any limit from the left will be $0$ but from the right hand side you will always be able to find a point that isn't close to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The convergence in this metric is precisely the uniform convergence. Suppose that $f_n$ converge uniformly. Then the limit is a continuous function $f$.  Also, since $f_n\to f$ uniformly, we also have $f_n\to f $ pointwise.

But you have computed the pointwise limit $\lim f_n$, and found that it is a discontinuous function: $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x) = 1\ne f(0)$. This proves that $f_n$ do not converge uniformly.